# I am geeting the output for the piece of code but NONE is getting appended as none should not come

Tags: python, list, math

```
def findLargestNumber(A):
    x=sorted(A)
    rev=x[::-1]
    final=''
    for digit in rev:
        final+=str(digit)
    print(final)
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    t=int(input()) #input 
    while(t>0):
        n=int(input())
        A=[int(x) for x in input().strip().split()] #list of number
        print(findLargestNumber(A))
        t-=1
```

As i have written this piece of code but i am not getting the output 
       but its showing none along with the output

```
1

5

31 30 34 51 92

9251343130

**None**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple reason for printing NONE, because your function returns nothing; 
Instead of printing 'final', you should return it

Replace this line:

print(final)

to

return final

```
final code seems like:
def findLargestNumber(A):
  x = sorted(A)
  rev = x[::-1]
  final = ''
  for digit in rev:
      final += str(digit)
  return final # <<< ---- here
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you are printing 2 things:

1. `print(findLargestNumber(A))`
2. `print(final)`

The second print statement prints your desired output. But the first print statement prints 'None' as no value is being returned from the function. Thus, it prints 'None'.

Modify your code to:

```
def findLargestNumber(A):
x = sorted(A)
rev = x[::-1]
final = ''
for digit in rev:
    final += str(digit)
print(final)

if __name__ == "__main__":
t = int(input())  # input
while(t > 0):
    n = int(input())
    A = [int(x) for x in input().strip().split()]  # list of number
    findLargestNumber(A)
    t -= 1
```

Just call the function and do not print it. It will do the work